# styling div with contenteditable = "false"

Tags: html

Following statement never changed the background color of div,

```html
<div id="msg" contenteditable="false" style=" background-color: aqua;"></div>
```

While if I set contenteditable="true" then it works,

```html
<div id="msg" contenteditable="true" style=" background-color: aqua;"></div>
```

How can I style contenteditable="false" ?

Comment: Tip: in cases like this, put a temporary `border: solid 1px red` on the element that you are trying to style, this would show that their heights are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, the background colour **is** set for the div… but it has `height: auto` (the default) and no content to make `auto` resolve to anything more than `0`. This leaves no visible pixels for the background to be painted on.

The contenteditable version gets an implied minimum height for the first line of content that the user can type into.